# How to suppress JSON error response from NewtonsoftJson in ASP.NET Core endpoint?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, json.net, httpresponse, endpoint

I have created a register user endpoint in an ASP.NET Core app. For that I am using the following DTO:

```
namespace CommandAPI.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    public class  RegisterUserDto
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string  Email { get; set; }     

        [Required]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

If I make a https call to this endpoint with following body :

```
[
  {
        "Email" : "abc@email.com",
        "Password" : "abc@123#"
  }
]
```

The endpoint returns the following error response :

```
{
  "errors": {
    "": [
      "Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'CommandAPI.Models.RegisterUserDto' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) to deserialize correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {\"name\":\"value\"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.\r\nPath '', line 1, position 1."
    ]
  },
  "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
  "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
  "status": 400,
  "traceId": "|3dcc7b94-4f57775eed318939."
}
```

Though the error is correct, but it contains my dto class name with namespace. How to suppress this detail in response?

I am using the following service to convert incoming json request to C# object :

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(s => s.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
```

Comment: I recommend leaving it, your DTO and its namespace is not a secret but the contract of your API, the client (you) provided an input that violates the specified contract and the error shows that.

Comment: Why do you want to suppress it? This is a validation error, not a random exception. `but it contains my dto class name with namespace.` yes. Those are part of your documentation and your Swagger schema already. If you posted `{"Email":"potato"}` you'd get a validation message saying that the `password` field is missing. The request you posted is something that's used by a registration form and any validation problems that aren't caught by the client/browser browser will have to be caught by the server and reported to the browser

Comment: Besides, if someone wants to sniff your API all they need to do is open that page and use either Fiddler or the browser's Developer Tools Network tab to inspect the requests.

Comment: If you want to be able to send the array body without an error, you should change your endpoint to accept a `List<RegisterUserDto>` since that is what you are sending.  If you want your endpoint to accept either a single object or an array of objects, see [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182).

Comment: If you still want the error but with a different message, does [Custom error response for incorrect json. Dotnet Core Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68485498/3744182) answer your question?

Comment: @dbc Yes. But I think others also have a valid point. To keep the behaviour as it is.

Comment: @VK - then if you don't need an answer any more you might go ahead and [delete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25088) this question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the querent has indicated in comments they no longer need this question answered.

Comment: @dbc I would say let it be there. This might be useful for some else, having the same doubt.